# How to update bootstrap progress bar.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular

The documentation on bootstrap progress bars illustrate how to display a progress bar with default values and completion value, but now how to update it? So, what's the simplest way to go about updating the value and width?

This is my progress bar in file home.html:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div id="trainingProgressBar" class="progress-bar 
        progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" 
        role="progressbar" 
        aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" 
        aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
        {{trainingProgress}}% Complete
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my home.ts file I declare my trainingProgress value:

```
public trainingProgress: number = 10;
```

The text will change to whatever trainingProgress is, but the width will not because trainingProgress isn't linked to `aria-valuenow` and `width:%`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [attribute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#attribute-binding) and [style](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#style-binding) binding:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div id="trainingProgressBar" class="progress-bar 
        progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" 
        role="progressbar" 
        aria-valuemin="0" 
        aria-valuemax="100" 
        [attr.aria-valuenow]="trainingProgress" 
        [style.width.%]="trainingProgress">
        {{trainingProgress}}% Complete
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/4wD0IFfbayxRnDN25nvA?p=preview)

Comment: It took me 15 mins to realize how it manages to show 0% and why it keeps showing only 0% even if whole text is 0% complete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width to trainingProgress using the `style` tag in your html.

It should look something like this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div id="trainingProgressBar" class="progress-bar 
        progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" 
        role="progressbar" 
        aria-valuemin="0" 
        aria-valuemax="100" style={{'width': trainingProgress + '%'}}>
        {{trainingProgress}}% Complete
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use your code snippet, I get the error:                                     Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'endSourceSpan' of null.